# Convert to one measuring unit

Tags: r, data-modeling

I have a datatset where the measure column has different units which I want to convert to one unit and remove the string (measuring unit)

[image]

```
> boston_cocktails %>% count(measure)
# A tibble: 42 x 2
  

     measure       n
       <chr>     <int>
     1 1            10
     2 1  3/4 oz     1
     3 1 1/2 oz    494
     4 1 1/4 oz     21
     5 1 2/3 oz      3
     6 1 3/4 oz      8
     7 1 750-ml      1
     8 1 dash        1
     9 1 oz       1102
    10 1 splash      1
```

Comment: Can you share sample data? Based on the screenshot I can only see 'oz'. No other unit

Comment: I edited the question showing the different types of measures the dataset has. Is it enough for you? cocktails <- readr::read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2020/2020-05-26/cocktails.csv')

Comment: That certainly is better. How would you want to convert the units. And what should be the common unit? E.g. how would you convert ml to oz?

Comment: Actually I want to build a predictive model from this dataset. For that I want a relationship between measure and ingredients to predict the name of the cocktail. For that only I thought of converting because it is not correct if I directly drop the string here. Is there any alternative you have for this issue?